# How to open a file of any type of extension with Android's "open with" option?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been stuck on a problem for almost 1 week, so I allow myself to call on you.

I would like from an application that I am currently developing, to be able to open a file of any type of extension from the internal storage of the phone.

Example in picture:

If I click on an .mp3 file from my application that I am developing, Android would have to recognize the type and automatically suggest applications on my phone that can play the file:

**"Ouvrir avec" means Open With**

[image]

The same goes for the other types.

PDF:

[image]

JPG:
[image]

Do you have a solution to answer my problem?

I tried many attempts, my last was this:

```
    String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Cours1.pdf";
   
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" + path), "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

But my file does not open:

[image]

Comment: If you are testing on Android 11+, your app will not have access to that file unless your app was the one that downloaded it.

Comment: I am on Android 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this :

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
private void openFile() {
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());
  MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
  File newFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Cours1.pdf");
 String ext = newFile.getName().substring(newFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    
    Intent inte = new Intent();
  inte.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.your.package.fileProvider", newFile);
   inte.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
  startActivity(inte);
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Here is what I use (it works fine with me):

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+path),mimeType);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(intent);
```

`path` and `mimeType` are `String`s

**Edit 2:**
replace `"content://"` with `"file://"`

If it worked please accept the answer and upvote it so more people can find it.

Comment: Sorry But it does not work :'(
I edited the code for my first post with a simpler and shorter attempt with which I am encountering the same error (at having a file not opening)

Comment: I edited my answer, please see Edit 1

Comment: It's worked for me using your code, Thanks You very much!!!! :D You save me!

Comment: Note that this code will not work on newer versions of Android, as the other app will not necessarily have access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

First go to manifest file and write the following tag under the `<application>` tag

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/providerpaths" />
</provider>
```

Then create a `xml` folder in `res` and create a file named: `providerpaths.xml` and then copy paste the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
  name="external_files"
  path="." />
</paths>
```

In java

```
private void openFile(Context context ,String filePath) {
  File file = new File(filePath);
  Uri uri =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(context.getApplicationContext()),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
   String mime = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

How to use

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Cours1.pdf";
  try {
    openFile(MainActivity.this ,path) ;
  }catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot open the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```